# Encoding Requests response - Python

Tags: python, api, encoding, python-requests

I can't figure out why I'm not getting the letters æøå from my response. ø = \u00d8
The documentation on the api says utf-8 and I've checked that r.encoding is utf-8

```
header = {'Client-Identifier': 'test'}
r = requests.get(url='https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json'
```

Is it a VS Code or Python setting I'm missing?

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

you can use request.json, response is basically in json.

```
header = {'Client-Identifier': 'test'}
r = requests.get(url='https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json')
print(r.json())
```

output contains  `'name': 'Økern Portal', 'address': 'Lørenfaret 1'`